# Возможно ли создать интерфейс для создания экземпляра одного из следующих классов?

Tags: c#, проектирование, шаблоны-проектирования

Добрый день! Пусть есть несколько классов, например:

```
public class ProductA 
{
   public string FieldFirst { get; set; }
   public string FieldSecond { get; set; }
   public string FieldThird { get; set; }
   public string FieldFourth { get; set; }
}

public class ProductB 
{
   public string FieldFirst { get; set; }
   public string FieldSecond { get; set; }
   public string FieldThird { get; set; }
   public List<AnotherClass1> FieldFourth { get; set; }
}

public class ProductC 
{
   public string FieldFirst { get; set; }
   public string FieldSecond { get; set; }
   public List<AnotherClass2> FieldThird { get; set; }
}

public class ProductD 
{
   public string FieldFirst { get; set; }
   public List<AnotherClass3> FieldSecond  { get; set; }
}
```

Собственно, хотел узнать, возможно ли сделать общий интерфейс для выбора класса и создания объекта. Нельзя ли найти какой-нибудь единый  интерфейс для них, и использовать, например  Абстрактную Фабрику. Или это нельзя сделать в данном случае. Заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: Интерфейс-то всегда можно, тривиальный. Скажите лучше, какую задачу вы пытаетесь решить? Какого вида код вы хотели бы написать, и как он должен работать?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Ну если коротко, у меня около 10 таких классов. Это пока, их число будет расти потом. У меня генерируется с одного модуля список токенов. И я хотел использовать какой то паттерн, который бы по входящему списку выбирал класс и создавал его экземпляр.  Но я не могу использовать Строителя, или Фабрику, потому, что у классов нет единого интерфейса. Вот такая у меня задача.

Comment: Может, вам просто нужен [DI-контейнер](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx)?

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! А не могли бы вы подсказать как это сделать конкретно? Я работал с ninject'ом , но не много. Например в обычном случае, у класса ProductE  есть интерфейс-поле InterfaceFirst и я, зная тип класса,  обращаюсь через 'AppKernel.Get<>()'.  Например 'var producte= AppKernel.Get<ProductE>();'  При этом  модуль ninject будет искать код у себя, типа 'this.Bind<InterfaceFirst>().To<AnotherClass4>();' и модуль проинициализирует объект. А как ninject, сможет определить сам тип? Где можно посмотреть такой пример! Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Ну, насколько я понимаю, вы должны зарегистрировать, кто и как будет создаваться. А что-то DI сможет выяснить сам, например, вытащить нужные конструкторы. Вот вроде бы описание: https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Dependency-Injection-With-Ninject

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Простое решение

Если **типы аргументов известны на стадии компиляции и наборы типов параметров уникальны**, то можно сделать банальную фабрику:

```
public static class ProductFactory
{
    public static ProductA Create (string fieldFirst, string fieldSecond, string fieldThird, string fieldFourth)
    {
        return new ProductA(fieldFirst, fieldSecond, fieldThird, fieldFourth);
    }

    public static ProductB Create (string fieldFirst, string fieldSecond, string fieldThird, List<int> fieldFourth)
    {
        return new ProductB(fieldFirst, fieldSecond, fieldThird, fieldFourth);
    }

    public static ProductC Create (string fieldFirst, string fieldSecond, List<double> fieldThird)
    {
        return new ProductC(fieldFirst, fieldSecond, fieldThird);
    }

    public static ProductD Create (string fieldFirst, List<float> fieldSecond)
    {
        return new ProductD(fieldFirst, fieldSecond);
    }
}
```

Тогда создание объектов будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
ProductA productA = ProductFactory.Create("1", "2", "3", "4");
ProductD productD = ProductFactory.Create("1", new List<float>());
```

Здесь я предположил следующие классы продуктов:

```
public class ProductA
{
    public string FieldFirst { get; set; }
    public string FieldSecond { get; set; }
    public string FieldThird { get; set; }
    public string FieldFourth { get; set; }

    public ProductA (string fieldFirst, string fieldSecond, string fieldThird, string fieldFourth)
    {
        FieldFirst = fieldFirst;
        FieldSecond = fieldSecond;
        FieldThird = fieldThird;
        FieldFourth = fieldFourth;
    }
}

public class ProductB
{
    public string FieldFirst { get; set; }
    public string FieldSecond { get; set; }
    public string FieldThird { get; set; }
    public List<int> FieldFourth { get; set; }

    public ProductB (string fieldFirst, string fieldSecond, string fieldThird, List<int> fieldFourth)
    {
        FieldFirst = fieldFirst;
        FieldSecond = fieldSecond;
        FieldThird = fieldThird;
        FieldFourth = fieldFourth;
    }
}

public class ProductC
{
    public string FieldFirst { get; set; }
    public string FieldSecond { get; set; }
    public List<double> FieldThird { get; set; }

    public ProductC (string fieldFirst, string fieldSecond, List<double> fieldThird)
    {
        FieldFirst = fieldFirst;
        FieldSecond = fieldSecond;
        FieldThird = fieldThird;
    }
}

public class ProductD
{
    public string FieldFirst { get; set; }
    public List<float> FieldSecond { get; set; }

    public ProductD (string fieldFirst, List<float> fieldSecond)
    {
        FieldFirst = fieldFirst;
        FieldSecond = fieldSecond;
    }
}
```

## Сложное решение

Если на стадии компиляции ничего не известно, а аргументы собираются вручную во время выполнения программы, то можно воспользоваться Autofac, например. Вот пример использования, когда выбор делается на основе имён и типов параметров, и имена параметров не совпадают с именами аргументов конструктора:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder
    .Register<IProduct>((c, p) => {
        switch (p.Count()) {
            case 4:
                if (p.OfType<NamedParameter>().Any(a => a.Name == "str4"))
                    return new ProductA(
                        p.Named<string>("str1"), p.Named<string>("str2"), p.Named<string>("str3"), p.Named<string>("str4"));
                else
                    return new ProductB(
                        p.Named<string>("str1"), p.Named<string>("str2"), p.Named<string>("str3"), p.Named<List<int>>("ints"));
            case 3:
                return new ProductC(
                    p.Named<string>("str1"), p.Named<string>("str2"), p.Named<List<double>>("doubles"));
            case 2:
                return new ProductD(
                    p.Named<string>("str1"), p.Named<List<float>>("floats"));
        }
        throw new DependencyResolutionException("Could not resolve product.");
    })
    .As<IProduct>();
IContainer container = builder.Build();

var productA = container.Resolve<IProduct>(
    new NamedParameter("str1", "1"),
    new NamedParameter("str2", "2"),
    new NamedParameter("str3", "3"),
    new NamedParameter("str4", "4"));
var productD = container.Resolve<IProduct>(
    new NamedParameter("str1", "1"),
    new NamedParameter("floats", new List<float>()));
```

Предполагается, что продукты реализованы следующим образом:

```
public interface IProduct
{}

public class ProductA : IProduct
{
    public string FieldFirst { get; set; }
    public string FieldSecond { get; set; }
    public string FieldThird { get; set; }
    public string FieldFourth { get; set; }

    public ProductA (string fieldFirst, string fieldSecond, string fieldThird, string fieldFourth)
    {
        FieldFirst = fieldFirst;
        FieldSecond = fieldSecond;
        FieldThird = fieldThird;
        FieldFourth = fieldFourth;
    }
}

public class ProductB : IProduct
{
    public string FieldFirst { get; set; }
    public string FieldSecond { get; set; }
    public string FieldThird { get; set; }
    public List<int> FieldFourth { get; set; }

    public ProductB (string fieldFirst, string fieldSecond, string fieldThird, List<int> fieldFourth)
    {
        FieldFirst = fieldFirst;
        FieldSecond = fieldSecond;
        FieldThird = fieldThird;
        FieldFourth = fieldFourth;
    }
}

public class ProductC : IProduct
{
    public string FieldFirst { get; set; }
    public string FieldSecond { get; set; }
    public List<double> FieldThird { get; set; }

    public ProductC (string fieldFirst, string fieldSecond, List<double> fieldThird)
    {
        FieldFirst = fieldFirst;
        FieldSecond = fieldSecond;
        FieldThird = fieldThird;
    }
}

public class ProductD : IProduct
{
    public string FieldFirst { get; set; }
    public List<float> FieldSecond { get; set; }

    public ProductD (string fieldFirst, List<float> fieldSecond)
    {
        FieldFirst = fieldFirst;
        FieldSecond = fieldSecond;
    }
}
```